Error in iterating over two loops in MATLAB
I'm writing a MATLAB script to assign ratings to people with a certain batting average score. For example, if it was below .200, it would be Bad, .220 is Below Average etc. I wrote this code to loop over every player in a table, then every rating to find the score to assign:
ratings = {'Bad', 'Below Average', 'Average', 'Above average', 'Great', 'Elite'};
AVGRatings = [0.200, 0.220, 0.255, 0.280, 0.310, 0.340, inf];


for j = 1:numel(AVGRatings)
    for i = 1:height(Batting)
        if Batting.AVG(i) < AVGRatings(j)
            Batting.AVG_Rating{i} = ratings{j};
            break;
        end
    end
end

For some reason, it loops to the 6th iteration of the Batting table and then throws this error:

Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 6.

Any help would be appreciated with this!
I've tried to change the loop order, and I've made the program more bespoke with this code:
for i = 1:height(Batting)
    fprintf('Player %d:\n', i);  % Print player index for debugging
    for j = 1:numel(AVGRatings)
        fprintf('  Trying rating %d\n', j);  % Print rating index for debugging
        if Batting.AVG(i) < AVGRatings(j)
            Batting.AVG_Rating{i} = ratings{j};
            fprintf('    Assigned rating %s\n', ratings{j});  % Print assigned rating for debugging
            break;
        end
    end
end

Player 1:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
    Assigned rating Above average
Player 2:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
  Trying rating 5
  Trying rating 6
    Assigned rating Elite
Player 3:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
  Trying rating 5
  Trying rating 6
    Assigned rating Elite
Player 4:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
  Trying rating 5
  Trying rating 6
    Assigned rating Elite
Player 5:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
  Trying rating 5
  Trying rating 6
    Assigned rating Elite
Player 6:
  Trying rating 1
  Trying rating 2
  Trying rating 3
  Trying rating 4
  Trying rating 5
  Trying rating 6
  Trying rating 7
Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 6.


Can you provide exactly the error including the line number as well as the sample input used for testing?  I suspect it's because AVGRatings has 7 entries and ratings has only six and you're doing a less-than comparison.

AVGRatings is one longer than ratings.

That was it. Thank you for your help all!
